# Displaying Ads on certain screen only (React Native & Navigation)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Im new to react native and navigation and wanna ask about how to show ads only at certain screen? For example i only want to show the ad on ScreenOne but not on ScreenTwo or ScreenThree and so on.

Right now im using react-native-admob to show the ads and write the code on the App.js

My code is Something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  View
  } from 'react-native';
import { AdMobBanner } from 'react-native-admob';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import StrataScreen from './screens/StrataScreen';
import DrawerNavigator from './screens/DrawerNavigator';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
          <AppStackNavigator />
          <AdMobBanner
            adSize='smartBannerLandscape'
            adUnitID='ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716'
          />
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Strata: StrataScreen,
  Drawer: {
    screen: DrawerNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    navigationOptions: {
      gestureEnabled: false
    }
  }
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at High Order Components, write a component that returns the component itself, plus the adMobBanner, then use return the screen you want wrapped inside this HOC.

https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Ok, lets suppose you want the ad on your login screen, you can import your HOC on app.js, and do

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
  Login: withAd(LoginScreen),
  Strata: StrataScreen,
  Drawer: {
    screen: DrawerNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    navigationOptions: {
      gestureEnabled: false
    }
  }
);
```

where withAd is the HOC you created and imported here, or you can change you LoginComponent, on the file itself to return withAd(LoginComponent) and just keep using the way you are, the decision you have the make is if, you gonna need that screen with ad on every moment, or just with this navigator.

Edit: To have the same ad on all screens, I would recommend you to use some state store, either redux, mobx or even React New Context API to store if the screen should render the ad, where you can wrap you adBanner to a component, and put some logic to check if should render the ad, where when you change to a screen you should or should not show, you dispatch an action to change that variable, and the adBanner will re-render accordingly.

Comment: ok i've already researched it. but now how to i return the screens i wanted?

Comment: post the 'theStackNavigator' please, there i can show you

Comment: here below your answer

Comment: okay ill try using your solution. thanks alot man! really appreciate it :)

Comment: welcome, here to help if it doesn't work, post your HOC here, if the problem is there

Comment: and mark as correct answer, if you think that it is, it always helps.

Comment: man it worked, but when i swiped the ad also get swiped. if i want it to be like same the whole time how to do it :) ? I want to show the ads on the 2 other screens

Comment: There is another way, I find it more ugly. I will edit my post.

Comment: hmmm ok ill research more about it. ill mark your answer as correct so maybe it'll help other people. thx man